# C: libpcap doesn't capture wlan0 packets

Tags: c, wireless, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

I'm new in C and got little confused. I've read some topics about this problem but none of them worked for me. I'm trying to capture wlan0 packets with libpcap but something goes wrong. **pcap_next()** function returns null but i can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void dump(const unsigned char *data_buffer, const unsigned int length)    {
   unsigned char byte;
   unsigned int i, j;

   for(i=0; i < length; i++) {
   byte = data_buffer[i];
   printf("%02x ", data_buffer[i]); // Display byte in hex.

   if(((i%16)==15) || (i==length-1)) {

   for(j=0; j < 15-(i%16); j++)
   printf(" ");
   printf("| ");

  for(j=(i-(i%16)); j <= i; j++) { // Display printable bytes from line.
   byte = data_buffer[j];

   if((byte > 31) && (byte < 127)) // Outside printable char range
    printf("%c", byte);

   else
    printf(".");
 }
   printf("\n"); // End of the dump line (each line is 16 bytes)

 } // End if
 } // End for

 }


int main() {
  struct pcap_pkthdr header;
  const u_char *packet;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
  char *device;
  pcap_t *pcap_handle;
  int i;
  device = "wlan0";


  printf("Sniffing on device %s\n", device);
  pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 4096, 1, 0, errbuf);


for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, &header);
  printf("Got a %d byte packet\n", header.len);
  dump(packet, header.len);
}

pcap_close(pcap_handle);

}
```

what i get as output is
 **Sniffing on device wlan0
 Got a 0 byte packet

Got a 0 byte packet
 Got a 0 byte packet**

This is how i compile **gcc -o test test.c -l pcap** and run the program as root. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever heard about code indenting?

Comment: *If NULL is returned, `errbuf` is filled in with an appropriate error message*.

Comment: Im sorry its pcap_next() which returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pcap_next() returns a pointer to the packet data on success, and
>   returns NULL if an error occured, or if no packets were read from a
>   live capture (if, for example, they were discarded because they didn't
>   pass the packet filter, or if, on platforms that support a read
>   timeout that starts before any packets arrive, the timeout expires
>   before any packets arrive, or if the file descriptor for the capture
>   device is in non-blocking mode and no packets were available to be
>   read), or if no more packets are available in a ''savefile.''
>   Unfortunately, there is no way to determine whether an error occured
>   or not.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_next

So it could be allright. My suggestion is to check for `NULL`, do nothing (or `i--;`) and go on with the next packet. OR use `pcap_next_ex()` and check for an error.
And does the `pcap_open_live()` even return a valid handle? Please check the return value.

Comment: And Linux is, with sufficiently new versions of libpcap and the kernel, a "[platform] that supports a read timeout that starts before any packets arrive", so `pcap_next()` could return NULL even if there are no errors.  `pcap_next()` is, for this reason, a bad routine to use, as you can't detect errors with it; use `pcap_next_ex()` instead.